# Spring+JPA+Hibernate+Postgres configuration

Tags: spring, hibernate, postgresql, jpa, configuration

I have configuration that works with MySQL, but I would like to switch to Postgres now. I would like to keep it without hibernate-specific classes and configuration files such as SessionFactory and hibernate.cfg.xml. And I would like to keep my persistence.xml minimal.
With the configuration below when the application starts on Tomcat I don't have the tables created automatically. Database fitnessTracker exists, Postgres server is running.
How can I test my configuration? Any advice on more verbose debug info at this stage is very welcome.

My configs:

web.xml

```
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:/jpaContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>    

<servlet>
<servlet-name>fitTrackerServlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
<init-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/servlet-config.xml</param-value>
</init-param>
</servlet>....</web-app>
```

jpaContext.xml (Postgres)

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd">

<context:annotation-config />

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="punit"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.pluralsight.model"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
        </bean>
    </property>

    <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>
            <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
            <entry key="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
        </map>
    </property>
 </bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/fitnessTracker"/>
    <property name="username" value="postgres"/>
    <property name="password" value="admin"/>
</bean>
```

META-INF/persistence.xml

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
version="2.0">
```

My Entity class

```
package com.pluralsight.model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Activity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

private String desc;

...getters and setters

}
```

Comment: What's your concrete question? If your question is "how do I test my configuration?", well, you start your app, play with it, and see if it works as expected. Or you write automated tests.

Answer (score 1):

The configuration was correct, the problem in my case was the absence of maven resources folder in the resultant war.